# How to view Images From the Folders in Server?

Tags: asp.net

I have a list of images for users. In the database the images table has these columns:

1. id
2. height
3. width
4. fileName
5. userName
6. userId

I have uploaded these images to the server in a specific folder. Therefore, the only thing that should be done, is to search the folder for the correct `fileName` for the logged-in user, and fetch the image.

When I login and view the gallery, I'd like to see my image on the screen. I've searched for it a long time, but no answer till now.

Comment: Poor English @Sammy ;). May we edit your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can write [ImageHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) to display [images](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETFuturesGeneratingDynamicImagesWithHttpHandlersGetsEasier.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

is that folder under your web applications iis folder? if not you have to create a virtual directory to that folder, so you can call it by url. eg. `http://<your host>/<images folder(virtual directory)>/<user id>.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Not that clear question but  i will try to solve it:

1. Get the file name according to the userId by some query .and store it in an
   variable  .
2. `string dir =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") +
                   "/" + FolderName + "/" + FileNameVarWithExtinsion;`
3. Set the ImageUrl by the the previous path.